# Calling concrete implementation of abstract method in base class, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm new to working with Python, and I'm trying to implement a structure that I use regularly in C#. I need to read in and process data from a bunch of different tables. There is a small amount of code that needs to be different for each table, but mostly it can be reused. Hence, I'm trying to create an abstract base class that handles most of the processing and that calls an abstract method for the table-specific processing. I then create concrete implementations of the class that implement these functions for each table. Unfortunately, the shared methods in the base class are calling the abstract methods, not the methods implemented in the child classes.

Here is a stripped down version of the abstract class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class AbstractDataResampler(object):
    __metaclass__  = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.client = database

        self.__configure_database()

    def __resample_data(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def get_resampled_data(self):
        return __resample_data()
```

And here's a stripped down version of a concrete implementation.

```
from DataProcessors.AbstractDataResampler import AbstractDataResampler as Parent
class SpecificDataResampler(Parent)
    def __init__(self, database):
        super().__init__(database)

    def __resample_data(self):
        ... implementation
```

When I create an instance of SpecificDataResampler and call get_resampled_data() I get a NotImplementedException, because the base version of __resample_data is being called, not the implemented child version.

```
resampler = SpecificDataResampler(db)
resampler.get_resampled_data()
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do in Python 3? I.e. for a child class to call a method implemented in the abstract base class, which then uses a method overridden by the child class?

I apologize if this is a duplicate, or there's a simple error at work. I've tried numerous suggestions online, but none have worked (I think many were for Python 2.7).

Note: this is a simplified version of things. The SpecificDataResampler is actually a singleton, following [this pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html), so SpecificDataResampler is actually a nested inner class. I have however test this without using the singleton pattern, and received the same error.

Comment: One of the most important reasons for existing the private methods is to not override them by superclasses. I think in this case you'd better go with a regular method and override it based on your need. You can then, control the behavior of your method based on the argument or etc. within the method itself.

Comment: It's possible if you override the `AbstractDataResampler.__dict__` item of `def __resample_data(self):`.